# How called javascript function after Response.Close()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I've a problem with called javascript function after close response in code behind in ASP.Net Web Forms.

MY CODE:

```
string CloseJS = "<script>window.parent.SaveToSAVAction.Close();</script>";

httpContext.Response.Clear();
httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
httpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",header);
httpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(viewModel.Create());
httpContext.Response.Flush();
httpContext.Response.Close();

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "closeScript", CloseJS);
```

Maybe somebody know how fixed it, or know better way to download byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Call JavaScript just before Closing Response.

Create `.aspx` Generic Handler To Download File then You can Call it something like this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Hide", "HideDiv()", true);
Response.Redirect("MyHandler.ashx")
```

OR

js function to hide div and Redirect

```
function HideDivNRedirect()
{
  //hide div
window.location.href='myhandler.ashx';
}

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Hide", "HideDivNRedirect();", true);
```